# Does wood shop sawdust work well for mushroom casing?

Tags: mushrooms

I have a friend with a home wood shop, and he said I can get his clean sawdust for free. Will this make good casing to keep things from drying out? Hay is a common casing for wine cap, so why not sawdust?

Comment: Hi Black Thumb! Would you please add some information to your title and question about what casing means? You have the "mushroom" tag so it obviously has something to do with growing mushrooms, but I'm confused. What is a casing in this context and what things would it keep from drying out? I apologize if it's something I should know, but in case more people like me are having trouble understanding, expanding the question would be great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this article on mushrooms on sawdust](https://freshcapmushrooms.com/learn/the-fruiting-block-growing-gourmet-mushroom-on-sawdust/), the authors claim that sawdust is great for some mushrooms, but it is helpful to choose sawdust from hardwoods. In addition the casing requires special sterilization attention, the use of particular grow bags and the addition of nitrogen.

Answer (score 3):

No Sawdust is not a good casing layer for mushrooms, a casing layer should provide a high humidity, aerated environment without providing nutrients to the growing mycelium. The humidity and lack of nutrients will trigger pinning in the mushrooms, if you have a casing layer which is nutritious (like sawdust) the mushrooms will just continue colonizing it, avoiding pinning and fruiting.

Hay will create a high humidity, aerated environment with relatively low nutrients. Sawdust will create a high humidity, non aerated, nutritious environment.

Here is a good post about the topic albeit from an indoor growing perspective.
https://ezmushroom.com/grow/making-a-casing-layer-for-growing-mushrooms/

Answer (score 1):

The answer, once again, is that it depends. If the sawdust comes from treated wood then certainly not. If the saw dust comes from untreated wood then it might be alright. Also, what type of mushroom are you talking about? For about 100 different species of mushroom I would say no but for many varieties I would say yes. I am assuming your talking about wincaps? If that's true then give it a shot. Its a very healthy variety and is quite stubborn once it spawns. So experiment and feel free to come back to this post at a later date in the future to divulge your results.

Comment: i know to never use treated sawdust, and i tend to talk about king stropharia